# coding without storyboards

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift4

I am following a tutorial video on how to allow users to edit their profile. In this tutorial, they are using storyboards and I am not. I was wondering, do I have to use storyboards in order to follow along? Or can I use their code to plug into mine without the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple documentation:

> A storyboard is a visual representation of the user interface of an
>   iOS application, showing screens of content and the connections
>   between those screens. A storyboard is composed of a sequence of
>   scenes, each of which represents a view controller and its views;
>   scenes are connected by segue objects, which represent a transition
>   between two view controllers.

As you are probably guessing, storyboards contain information about widgets, animations, views that are required by the code you will be adding `to yours`. Additionally, Storyboards also contain the connection between the visual elements and the code (outlets and actions). All of that can be created programmatically but the code you will be pasting from this tutorial, if it's coming from a project that includes storyboards, won't contain this associated logic.

So, at this point, it would seem highly unwise to add complexity to your tutorial to recreate these elements at once. What I would suggest is for you to follow the tutorial and then try to remove some of these elements and replace them by code to obtain similar results just as an exercise to learn. Keep in mind that Storyboards have been around to simplify the design of UI in the application, so I would recommend for you to master their usage instead of shying away from them.